# using the command line how can i modify filenames

Tags: cmd, filenames

how can i modify filenames in a folder based on delimiters in the filename?

I have a folder with images that get picked up by a different program based on a schedule- the program can only analyze the images if it contains just the main name (sku#) not the additional data that the photographers add after the name

using the command line can i run some sort of script to modify the filenames & delete all characters from after an underscore or hyphen (also need to delete underscore or hyphen)

(i dont know if & how its possible to do this thru the windows command line but i do have the option of running such a 'script' in cygwin- I prefer to use whatever works best...)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of these filenames?

Comment: I assume you're in a windows environment, but it would be good if you specified the OS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a need to do this: but with a quick search I found [this link on another Stack Exchange site.](https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

A few people uploaded some powershell scripts. The top answer is a GUI tool to do mass name-changes.

There is this CMD example:

```
dir /B > fileList.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %i in (fileList.txt) DO ren "%i %j %l" %l
```

> The first line outputs the list of files into a file called fileList.txt. The second line separates each of the names in the list into 3 parts, the #, the "-" and the rest of the name. For each of those it does the rename command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr "_ -"') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=_-" %%i IN ("%%a") DO ECHO REN "%%a" "%%i%%~xa" 2>nul
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr "_ -"') DO ECHO failed ON "%%a"
```

This should do the job.

First step is to perform a directory listing in `/b` basic form (without headers - names only) and `/a-d` without directory names. This is filtered by `findstr` on (either underscore or dash) and %%a acquires each filtered filename in turn.

The next step is to take those filenames and split them into the parts on either `_` or `-`. The first token (up to, but not including the delimiter) is applied to %%i, so the `rename` required is from `"%%a"` (the original filename) to `"%%i%%~xa"` - the first token+the extension from the original filename.

It's quite possible that the attempt to rename will fail because the new name already exists, so the error message is simply ignored (`2>nul`)

Finally, look for any un-renamed files and report them (optional, of course)

Note that the `REN`ame command is merely `ECHO`ed. This ensures nothing is actually changed while you verify this is what you want to do. Simply remove the `ECHO` before the `REN` to activate the rename.